# SendGrid only sends emails to Gmail

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to integrate SendGrid API via phpMailer (also tried with php API library too). In localhost and live server I got 250 OK with phpmailer and 202 OK with API library response.

After submission (4 receiver), I've only receive 1 email to gmail. Another domain email addresses shows Delivered in SendGrid activitiy page but I dont receive these emails except Gmail.

My sender email adress and domain address already verified. Whats wrong on my code?

phpMailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host          = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
$mail->Port          = 587;
$mail->Username      = 'apikey';
$mail->Password      = 'API_KEY';
$mail->SMTPAuth      = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug     = true;
$mail->Debugoutput   = 'html';
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
$mail->Priority = 3;
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->SetFrom('sender@mail.com', $name = 'Sender Title');
$mail->AddAddress('receiver@mail.com', 'Receiver Title');
$mail->Subject  =  'SendGrid Test';
$mail->MsgHTML('Mail body');
$sending = $mail->Send();
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

With API Library

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("sender@mail.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("receiver@mail.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('API_KEY');
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

Comment: Some minor issues here, probably not the cause. SMTPDebug takes an int, SMTPSecure should be `tls`, I’d avoid base64 as your encoding, priority probably unnecessary. Do you get access to delivery logs on sendgrid?

Comment: Are you sending using a From email address on a [domain that you authenticated with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication)?

Comment: @philnash yes, from email address and domain verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your emails are sending successfully and being received by Gmail, then there is nothing wrong with your code (save for the minor issues that Synchro pointed out in the comments).

[Email deliverability](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/deliverability) isn't an exact science, so there could be something in the contents of your email that triggers mail blocking for some inboxes. I'd follow the guidelines in this article on [email deliverability](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/deliverability) to ensure you are setting yourself up to get emails into inboxes.

Beyond that, I would also set up the [SendGrid Event Webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/tracking-events/event). That will delivery you events based on what your emails are doing, including delivery events when an email is dropped, deferred, bounced, blocked or delivered. That may help you understand what is happening to your email.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after entering article data in my test e-mail content. Also thanks for the suggestion I'll try the webhook.